# estimate scale parameter by using scipy.stats.gamma and scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to estimate the scale parameter by using the `scipy.stats.gamma` and `scipy.optimize.minimize`, along with my data.
I establish a function to be evaluated:

```
def loss_func(para, x, y):
    return sum((gamma.cdf(x, para[0], para[1])-y)**2)/2
```

and

```
res=minimize(loss_func, ini0, (x ,y), method='nelder-mead')
```

In this way, will `res.x[1]` return scale parameter and will `res.x[0]` return the shape parameter?

Comment: any reason you are not using `gamma.fit_loc_scale` or `gamma.fit` ?

Comment: Right. Because I only know cdf but not pdf of data.

Comment: take a look at `help( gamma.fit )` and `help( gamma.fit_loc_scale )`

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think you are getting it right. See the documentation for `scipy.stats` for cumulative distribution function method:`.cdf(x, a, loc=0, scale=1)`, with your function:

```
def loss_func(para, x, y):
    return sum((gamma.cdf(x, para[0], para[1])-y)**2)/2
```

`para[0]` becomes `a` and hence shape parameter and `para[1]` becomes `loc` , which is the location parameter. So as the result, `res.x[1]` return the location and `res.x[0]` returns shape, which is not quite what you want.

So you should change your function to:

```
def loss_func(para, x, y):
    return sum((gamma.cdf(x, para[0], scale=para[1])-y)**2)/2
```

Now, keep in mind that your are essentially doing a least square minimization to fit empirical CDF to the Gamma CDF. What @behzad.nouri suggested, to use the `.fit()` method, is a maximum likelihood method. These two are different and the results are expected to be different. If you have the raw data (instead of the empirical CDF), you may be better off using the `.fit()` or `.fit_loc_scale()` methods.